# CountDownLatch equivalent

Tags: java, c++, c++11

For some concurrent programming I could use the Java's [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) concept. Is there an equivalent for C++11 or what would that concept be called in C++?

What I want is to invoke a function once count has reached zero.

If there is non yet I would write myself a class like the following:

```
class countdown_function {
public:
  countdown_function( size_t count );
  countdown_function( const countdown_function& ) = default;
  countdown_function( countdown_function&& ) = default;
  countdown_function& operator=( const countdown_function& ) = default;
  countdown_function& operator=( countdown_function&& ) = default;
  // Callback to be invoked
  countdown_function& operator=(std::function<void()> callback);
  countdown_function& operator--();
private:
  struct internal {
    std::function<void()> _callback;
    size_t _count;
    // + some concurrent handling
  };
  // Make sure this class can be copied but still references
  // same state
  std::shared_ptr<internal> _state;
};
```

Is something similar already available anywhere?

Scenario is:

```
countdown_function counter( 2 );
counter = [success_callback]() {
  success_callback();
};

startTask1Async( [counter, somework]() {
  somework();
  --counter;
}, errorCallback );

startTask2Async( [counter, otherwork]() {
  otherwork();
  --counter;
}, errorCallback );
```

Comment: What exactly is the use for this?

Comment: I added a usage example.

Comment: So you basically want to execute a callback when all async tasks have completed? If yes, you can just directly abuse `shared_ptr`'s deleter and ditch the manual decrement.

Comment: If the code would really be that easy you would indeed be right. I added another (`error`)callback to the example, in which case I do not want `success_callback` to be called. That's the reason I am not using shared_ptr`'s deleter.

Comment: There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3600.html) covering this for the next C++ standard. An implementation is available as part of the [gcl](https://code.google.com/p/google-concurrency-library/).

Comment: @JohnSchug Indeed, [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-concurrency-library/source/browse/include/countdown_latch.h). Can you please go ahead and make this an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3600.html) covering this for the next C++ standard. An implementation is available as part of the [google concurrency library](https://code.google.com/p/google-concurrency-library/).

Comment: While `gcl::countdown_latch' is not really what I am looking for (since it is a blocking variant), I think you answered the title question the best. And I would really like to replace `countDown` with `--` but that is just me.

Answer (score 2):

I've often wished for the same thing. Here's one way to do it ...

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

class CountDownLatch {
public:
    explicit CountDownLatch(const unsigned int count): m_count(count) { }
    virtual ~CountDownLatch() = default;

    void await(void) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (m_count > 0) {
            m_cv.wait(lock, [this](){ return m_count == 0; });
        }
    }

    template <class Rep, class Period>
    bool await(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& timeout) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        bool result = true;
        if (m_count > 0) {
            result = m_cv.wait_for(lock, timeout, [this](){ return m_count == 0; });
        }

        return result;
    }

    void countDown(void) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (m_count > 0) {
            m_count--;
            m_cv.notify_all();
        }
    }

    unsigned int getCount(void) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_count;
    }

protected:
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    unsigned int m_count = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cassert>

class ThreadLatch
{
public:
    ThreadLatch(std::size_t count = 0)
        : _count(count) {}
    void inc()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        ++_count;
    }
    void dec()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        assert(0 != _count);
        --_count;
        if (0 == _count)
            _condition.notify_all();
    }
    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        while (_count > 0)
            _condition.wait(lock);
    }
private:
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _condition;
    std::size_t _count;
};
```

to be used this way

```
ThreadLatch g_latch;

void func(int worktime)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(worktime));
    printf("thread: work finished\n");
    g_latch.dec();
}

int main()
{
    int worktime = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<5 ;i++)
    {
         g_latch.inc();
         std::thread t(func, worktime);
         t.detach();
         worktime+=500;
    }

    g_latch.wait();
    printf("no more thread left: clean_exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).